# Android Studio Giving errors for default code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Alright, lets start this off.

I have had android studio for a weeks now, and at first it started of fine. But a couple days ago it started giving me errors for default code. The first thing I saw when I opened up a new project was an error that told me that R could not be resolved. Along with that, when I tried to create a text box, it worked in the display, but when I went into the text it told me that "This view is not constrained." I continued however, And when it became time to run the code, it gave me an error telling me that the installation failed. I have already looked around the internet and I rebuilt the project, cleaned it, invalidated catches and even completely reinstalled it however it still gives me errors.

Any ideas?

Screenshots:

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1igtPqAZWtgfqmUUPMCkyW8MNgyytojTd96dfgPT9eik/edit?usp=sharing - .R

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/14WvHMzVJVqAuPLmKwNySV5oXvW7kCNw2gh3g0G2Bow8/edit?usp=sharing - View is not constrained

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking updates for android studio.

Comment: I tried that today, However the errors were still the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a new project and copying and pasting your code into the new project? That might solve the R problem. For the TextView, if you don't need the constraint layout change it to a different layout. Hope this solves your problems.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the code, It gave me the same R error after 5 minutes.

Comment: For text view, how do you change it to a different layout? I am sorry if I am asking something obvious but I have only been coding for a couple weeks now.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the R error. To change the layout you have to change `<android.support.contraint.ConstraintLayout>` to `<LinearLayout>`. The closing tags should automatically change to `</LinearLayout>`.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't change the layout to linear but I was able to change it to a relative layout and the errors for the text box were gone.

Comment: Great! Glad that helped.